# Como escalar um bitmap rapidamente

Tags: android, otimização, jogos, bitmap, redimensionamento

Eu estou fazendo um jogo usando o SurfaceView e eu preciso que um bitmap tenha ,por exemplo ,um tamanho de 20x20 ,porém esse bitmap é reutilizado em outras partes do código em tamanhos diferentes ,ou seja ,não seria viável ele ter já as dimensões adequadas porque perderia muito a qualidade. O problema que estou enfrentando é que o bitmap em seu tamanho normal o jogo roda entre 45 e 50 FPS ,já quando eu escalo ele ,mesmo já pré escalado , o FPS cai drasticamente para de 10 a 20 FPS. Minha dúvida é como fazer com que ao escalar o bitmap o FPS não caía tanto?

OBS 1: Estou usando o método nativo `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`.

OBS 2: Se necessário ,não existe em pedir mais informações ou trechos do código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O processo de escalar uma imagem é bastante custoso, principalmente quando você quer aumentar a imagem. Para reduzir, os algoritmos de escala podem simplesmente aplicar uma média (algo como: o pixel da imagem em escala reduzida é o valor médio dos pixels daquela região na imagem original), mas para aumentar não tem como fugir de uma interpolação (algo como: os pixels da imagem aumentada são calculados a partir da taxa de variação da região na imagem original, considerando a nova dimensão). Por isso, **não se faz** escala em imagens dentro do main loop de um jogo, pois isso derruba mesmo o FPS.

O que é mais comum é você ter previamente produzidas versões em diferentes escalas da imagem, e utilizar a versão apropriada dependendo do local/dispositivo/etc. Se vc tem muitas imagens ou não tem como produzir isso previamente, use imagens em uma escala mais alta e reduza a escala **fora do mainloop do jogo** (antes de começar, por exemplo). O uso de imagens em escala mais alta também ajuda a manter uma resolução melhor (a resolução da interpolação não é das melhores).